# Does anyone know of an equivalent to trader test?

Tags: trading

I've been looking at forums that provide links to prep for trading interviews and TraderTest.org always pops up however, the website is down. Does anyone know what happened to the website or what are alternatives? I don't just want the mental math part, I also want to be able to answer the probability and brainteaser questions in an interview

Comment: I don’t know this website. I found that Mark Joshi’s and Timothy Falcon Crack’s books are good for general brainteaser and probability interview preparation.

Comment: @LocalVolatility ah thank you! I saw Timothy Falcon Crack's book and I think it's great. But i wanted an online timed exam that more likely resembles a timed interview

Comment: @user130306 a timed test online isn't really the same as the way you talk through answers in an interview is it though?

Comment: arithmetic questions are timed and kind of like an exam, there is no talking through the interview

Answer (score 4):

Unsure if people are still reading this but I would like an update since most of these don’t work anymore. I am currently using:

[zetamac.com](https://arithmetic.zetamac.com/) (has customizable number ranges but doesn't allow for decimals),

[tradermath.org](https://www.tradermath.org/) (seems to be made to resemble the actual test for flow but costs money unfortunately),

and [rankyourbrain.com](https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math) (has decimal questions but the they appear to be too difficult to be representative).

Please hit me up personally or comment below if you know of any other viable websites!

Answer (score 3):

[zetamac](http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/) is one, if you found others I am interested to know!

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar site.
Check this out:
https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math/mental-math-test-easy

Answer (score 1):

when I was interviewing for flow traders their HR recommended practice source http://www.calculationrankings.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://tradermaths.com has the same scoring method as Optiver and the questions are customizable.

Comment: How many digits and decimals should I use here?

Answer (score 1):

I've built https://mentalmath.online/ as an alternative - it focuses specifically on problems you'll likely face during trading interviews.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://graduatetrader.com/ they have 50 maths tests, each 8 mins long with 80 questions and negative marking. You can also make a profile to log your results.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tools on [tradinginterview.com](https://www.tradinginterview.com). Next to fixed tests and company tests (Flow Traders math test, Optiver 80 in 8), they also have a customisable math practice tool, so you can just practice the questions which you find hard.